# How to listen to Android GoogleMap pan and zoom

Tags: android, maps

I am using Android GoogleMap class (Google Play Services 8.1.0) and want to track map position change, that can be made by pan or zoom inside screen.

With the event, I need to update the places, according to map center.

In the previous APIs it was possible, but now I didnt find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a setOnCameraChangeListener

[setOnCameraChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnCameraChangeListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener))

Comment: careful, this will be called even if the program makes the map change and not user interaction.

Comment: This method deprecated

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the methods that listens to the camera move (e.g. setOnCameraMoveStartedListener, setOnCameraMoveCancelledListener etc) and check the reason:

```
googleMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
            if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
                //map is touched..do something
            }
        }
    });
```